# jQuery ajax method not accepting PlainObject as data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-400

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/handler",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: data_all,
  })
.done(function(r) { ...stuff... })
.fail(function(r) { ...stuff... });
```

`data_all` is a dictionary (e.g., `{"a":1, "b":2}`). Running this code currently returns a 400 error (using django, in case relevant). If I make one change:

```
  ...
  data: JSON.stringify(data_all),
  ...
```

It all works.

The thing is, that shouldn't be the case. The jQuery AJAX docs clearly states that the `data` argument accepts strings, arrays, and PlainObjects. When in debugger mode (using Chrome dev tools), I have verified that `data_all` is a PlainObject:

```
jQuery.isPlainObject(data_all)  # returns "true"
```

I'm using jQuery 2.1.4, so this should be there. Any idea why this requires the `stringify` function?

Comment: @Mikey - thanks, fixed

Comment: Right, you can give it an object. But jQuery will not auto-convert said object to match your given content type. an Object is not json, jquery will convert that object to a param string, thus giving you invalid data for your content type. It's all in the docs.

Comment: Look at the Network tab in your browser's Developer tools and see what gets passed to the service in each case. You could also try setting `processData: false` in your ajax options object.

Comment: processData: false while still using an object will not have the expected results. (i would expect it to result in the body containing `[object Object]`)

Comment: @KevinB - But stringify doesn't output json object either, it's a string representation of json data. There's something going on under the hood either way. (I think...)

Comment: No, json.stringify outputs a string. jQuery will not modify strings, so it gets passed to the body directly.

Comment: Curious why the downvote as well, I tried to do my research on this and it doesn't seem obvious to me.

Comment: Your title states that jquery isn't accepting a plain object as data, but it is accepting a plain object as data. It just isn't converting said object to the format your server expects. *It wasn't designed to do so*.

Comment: @KevinB - That just reflects my not understanding that there's a conversion required, it wasn't intended to be intentionally misleading. Ah well, to each his own. If you write your comment as  an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138015/discussion-between-eykanal-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *send* json data with jquery, you must stringify the object before passing it to jQuery; jQuery will not do it for you.

Under the hood, If the processData parameter is true (it is by default) and the data parameter doesn't contain a string, the value of the data parameter is passed to `$.param()` which creates a param string. Therefore, if you pass an object to the data param, your request body will contain `a=1&b=2`. If you simply set processData to false, jquery will skip the `$.param` process and directly send the .toString value of your object to the request body, which is `[object Object]`, so that's not going to work either. If you stringify the object to JSON, it will be a string and jQuery will pass it through unchanged to the request body.